# Control Build Result in TFS2015

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I'm using TFS2015 build definitions. Basically, I have a definition with a Visual Studio Build task and then a Visual Studio Test task. In this set up, if the Build task succeeds, but the Test task fails, the entire build fails. Is there a way to get this to set the result to "partiallySucceeded?"

The reason I want to do this is for our CodedUI tests. I want to be able to test a "partiallySucceeded" build using Release Management, but currently all of our builds are either "succeeded" or "failed," even though some of the "failed" ones are only due to 1 or 2 unit tests.

Comment: Did you check the "Continue on Error" checkbox?

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Thought I'd tested it both ways, but apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely bitten by the lack of the save and queue button in 2015.

Comment: What's the detail build log? Can you share it on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the "continue in error" checkbox on the test task.